# BottomSheetBehavior is not showing view in view binding Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, bottom-sheet, android-viewbinding

Hey i have activity class and activity layout, inside that i am calling another layout id in BottomSheetBehavior. The view is not showing to me it showing blank screen.

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
import com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.bottom_sheet_layout.*

class XYZ : BaseActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: XYZLayout
    private val behavior: BottomSheetBehavior<CoordinatorLayout> by lazy {
          val bottomSheetBinding = BottomSheetLayoutBinging.inflate(layoutInflater)
          val sheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheetBinding.bottomSheetRoot)
          sheetBehavior.addBottomSheetCallback(object : BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) {}

            override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, newState: Int) {
            }
        })
        sheetBehavior
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = XYZLayout.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
    }
}
```

I am calling **behavior** object on click listener

**BottomSheetLayout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_root"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:behavior_fitToContents="true"
        app:behavior_hideable="true"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="0dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

      .........

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: What is layoutInflator here and how it is getting initialized? Add complete code here.

Comment: @sak `layoutInflator` is [Google Developer](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#activities) i am using from here view binding.

Answer (score 1):

`BottomSheetBehavior.from()` param should be the `view` that has `app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"` setted